AWS lambda:InvokeFunction AccessDeniedException
I am trying to call a python lambda function from within another lambda function using:
client = boto3.client('lambda')
response = 
client.invoke(FunctionName=arn,InvocationType='RequestResponse',
Payload=json.dumps(data))

But I run into the following AccessDenied error:
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Invoke
operation: User: arn:aws:sts::nnnn:assumed-role/lambda-s3-full-access/cache-simdata-srv
is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-
west-1:nnnn:function:cache-s-s
I had a similar problem before but was never able to figure out what polices to add to the lambda execution role. Currently both lambdas has the following execution role:
AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

I am grateful for any advice.

None of those 3 roles you have assigned to your Lambda functions allow them to invoke other Lambda functions. You need to assign a role to the function that allows lambda:InvokeFunction.

I know, that is what I am asking for

What is the actual question? What pre-built, AWS managed policy to add? You should really create your own custom policy with just the permissions you need, to follow the principal of least privilege.

The question is of course how to solve the above problem.
I am not too familiar with AWS roles and polices, that is why I post the question here. But thanks, I will try to create a new  policy and attach to the existing role
